# Need help with a triangle related rates problem?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

[image]
I need a deeper explanation to why what I did is correct or not correct, and any help is greatly appreciated. Like if there's another way of solving these questions would you mind showing it to me too?

a) Show that the angle $u$ is given by $cotu = \frac{x}{a}$

What I did: we know that $cotu = \frac{cosu}{sinu}$ and $cosu = \frac{x}{A}$, $sinu=\frac{a}{A}$

which will give us $cotu = \frac{\frac{x}{A}}{\frac{a}{A}}$ which gives us the desired answer.

b) When the stample(stempel) is moving, becomes $x(t)$ and $u(t)$ two functions of time. Show that $u'(t)=-\frac{sin^2u(t)}{a}x'(t)$

My answer: We already know that $cotu = \frac{x}{a}$. Next step is to derive with regards to t.

giving us $\frac{1}{-sin^2u(t)}u'(t)=\frac{x'(t)}{a}$ Solving for $u'(t)$

$\frac{\frac{x'(t)}{a}}{\frac{1}{-sin^2u(t)}}$ which gives us the desired answer.

c) Assume that the stample is moving with a steady velocity 5cm/s from the left to the right and that the diameter is 10 cm. How quickly does does the angle $u$ change 2 seconds after the stample has passed the point A?

What I did: Using pythagoras which gives us

$A^2(t)=x^2(t)+100 cm$

We know that $x'(t) = 5 m/s$ We wish to find $A'(t)$

Now we derive with regards to $t$

$2A(t)*A'(t)=2x(t)*x'(t)+0$

Which gives us that

$A'(t)=\frac{x(t)*x'(t)}{A(t)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (c), you are asked to find $u'(2)$. Use the result from part (b). You are given that $a=10$ and $x'(2) = 5$, so you need to know what $u(2)$ is. After two seconds, $x=10$ as well. Can you use that to determine $u(2)$ and then get the answer?

Comment: Yeah, I realised that how i did it wasn't correct.

Comment: I got the answer: 1/4 cm/s now. I dont know if that's correct.. :/

Comment: Should be $-\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: oh damn it, forgot the $-$. Silly me :P, thanks rogerl.

Comment: it shouldn't matter that much? Since the velocity is the same? And they aren't asking for the direction of the velocity? Correct me if I am wrong @rogerl

Comment: The angle is decreasing. True, the question asks how fast it's changing. An answer like "decreasing at 1/4 cm/s" is probably what's desired.

Comment: One more question i tried to solve it in another way with sine and pythagoras. Led me to $sinu(t)=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+x(t)^2}} = \frac{10}{\sqrt{10^2+x(t)^2}}$ i dont know what to do with the $x(t)^2$ i know that the answer should give me $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: If you recognize that you are looking for the value at $t=2$, then you get $\sin u(2) = \frac{10}{10^2+10^2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ since $x(2) = 10$,